# Does the params and the name affect the command in Linux?

Tags: command, arguments, options

I see the tutorial, when create a user:

```
useradd -g liao1 lamp
```

You see they place the `-g liao1` before the `lamp`,
and I tested the:

```
useradd lamp -g liao1
```

I put the param after the name, I can create the user too, but I am not sure if there is distinction.

Comment: It depends on how the program is written to parse command line options/arguments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ivanivan noted, the interpretation of the line parameters is done by the program (`useradd`) in your case. Many programs don't care about the order of the parameters, but some do.

Eg. `convert` (from the imagemagick package) converts images and specifies:

```
convert [input-option] input-file [output-option] output-file
```

So, the input-option(s) have to be specified before the input file, and similar for the output-option(s).

There are much more complicated examples, such as compilers, which need options to be in a specific order in order to work correctly.

In all cases, it's very advisable to consult the `man pages` of the command, or the --help (or -h or -? or whatever) of the program you want to run. Things *can* go wrong...